# w and h must be numbers

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-functions

I'm having a tough time recreating [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-blob-resize-function-node) example. I'm getting the following output:

> 2019-08-19T17:19:24.531 [Information] Executing 'Functions.PdfToTiffConverter' (Reason='EventGrid trigger fired at 2019-08-19T17:19:24.4859961+00:00', Id=161802cf-f5b9-4555-8e36-a9ca7e0daf91)
>   2019-08-19T17:20:26.112 [Information] Error: w and h must be numbers
>       at Jimp.throwError (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules@jimp\utils\dist\index.js:26:13)
>       at Jimp.resize (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules@jimp\plugin-resize\dist\index.js:38:36)
>       at Jimp.read.then (D:\home\site\wwwroot\PdfToTiffConverter\index.js:14:19)

Here's my `function.json`:

```
{
  "disabled": false,
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventGridTrigger",
      "name": "myEvent",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "name": "myBlob",
      "type": "blob",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "{data.url}",
      "connection": "AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING",
      "datatype": "binary"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
const stream = require('stream');
const Jimp = require('jimp');

const storage = require('azure-storage');
const blobService = storage.createBlobService();

module.exports = (context, myEvent, myBlob) => {

  const widthInPixels = process.env.THUMBNAIL_WIDTH;
  const blobName = myEvent.subject.split('/')[6];

    Jimp.read(myBlob).then((thumbnail) => {

        thumbnail.resize(widthInPixels, Jimp.AUTO);

        thumbnail.getBuffer(Jimp.MIME_PNG, (err, buffer) => {

            const readStream = stream.PassThrough();
            readStream.end(buffer);

            blobService.createBlockBlobFromStream('thumbnails', blobName, readStream, buffer.length, (err) => {
                context.done();
            });
        });

    }).catch(context.log);
};
```

**What am I doing wrong? Why I am getting this exception?**

Comment: What exactly is the value of `widthInPixels`? If you're getting it straight from `process.env` I very strongly suspect it's a *string*, not a number.

Comment: Try `const widthInPixels = Number(process.env.THUMBNAIL_WIDTH);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like @Pointy pointed, the value of process.env.THUMBNAIL_WIDTH is a string, not a number.

[image]

[image: process.env.THUMBNAIL_WIDTH]

Try with `const widthInPixels = Number(process.env.THUMBNAIL_WIDTH);`